# Redirect single file or directory using bubblewrap

Tags: shell-script, container

I was wondering how one would use bubblewrap (`bwrap`) to redirect a single directory or file on Linux, while still allowing access to all other files?

For example, if I wanted to make Firefox conform to the XDG spec, I might do something like:

```bsh
bwrap \
  --bind $HOME/.config/mozilla $HOME/.mozilla \
  --bind / / \
  /usr/bin/firefox;
```

Obviously, I tried the above with no luck.

If anyone has the solution, I'd appreciate the help a lot. The mess of non-XDG-compliant directories in my home directory is driving me insane.

Comment: When you say "no luck", what happened? Did you get an error message, or did Firefox simply still use `~/.mozilla`?

Comment: The latter; Thank you for the answer! I'd upvote but I have less than 15 reputation on the unix stackexchange

Comment: You might want to look into [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com) as well as `bwrap`.  there are lots of example profiles/configs for running various applications with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to simply change the order of the `bind` arguments:

```
bwrap --bind / / --bind ~/.config/mozilla ~/.mozilla
```

It's not mentioned in [the `bwrap` manual page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/bwrap.1), but the order of `bind` operations matters. Whichever comes last will take precedence and "mask" the contents of any already-mounted filesystem. More simply:

```
$ find                                                                                                                                                                                                             
.
./a
./a/A
./b
./b/B
$ bwrap \
    --bind / / \                                                                                                                                                                                               
    --bind $(pwd)/a $(pwd)/b \
    ls b
A
```

(I'm not completely sure why `$(pwd)/a` is necessary, but if I use just relative paths like `./a` it gives me `permission denied` for some reason)